# Visualizing multisource Breadth-First Search (BFS) on large dataset

Tags: python, data-visualization, graph-neural-network, c++, interactive-visualization

I have a very large dataset (2.4 million vertices and 123 million edges) and I'd like to visualize running multisource Breadth-First Search (BFS) on it. In particular, each starting node is given a different color, and when a colored node's unvisited neighbor is popped from the queue, that neighbor gets the same color (kind of like floodfill but with multiple colors). I already have the BFS algorithm implemented, and I have a way to track which nodes have been visited and what color they are. I am just not sure on the best way to *visualize* it. Does anyone have a library or program that can make this easy? Ideally I'd be able to make an animation, but it would also be fine if I could just make a still-frame image for each bfs iteration. Ideally something in python or C++, but I can work with another language if necessary.

I saw that there is a python library called [cuGraph](https://github.com/rapidsai/cugraph), although it seemed complicated and I wasn't able to understand if it could be applied to this use case/if I need special hardware to run it.

Apologies if this has been asked before, I wasn't able to find an immediate answer when I was searching the site. Also sorry if this question is more programming-oriented, I tried asking on StackOverflow but it's not allowed by their rules.

Comment: I assume that "BFS" is a breadth-first search. Please edit. Also, it's already hard to visualize a graph of this size in the first place, so it would be good if you could give a few more ideas of what this is about. (And then I think it would be a reasonable question in the [tag:data-visualization] tag.)